# If a function is defined by $f(x)=\arcsin(\sin(\frac{x+\sin x}{2}))~\forall x\in[0,\pi]$ then

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima, inverse-function

[image]
I tried differentiating the function given but the problem is that it changes with intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the *usual* codomain of $\;\arcsin\;$ , we have that $\;\arcsin:[-1,1]\to\left[-\frac\pi2,\,\frac\pi2\right]\;$ . Now

$$x\in[0,\pi]\implies0\le\frac{x+\sin x}2\le\frac{\pi+\sin\pi}2=\frac\pi2\implies0\le\sin\left(\frac{x+\sin x}2\right)\le1$$

and thus

$$f(x):=\arcsin\sin\left(\frac{x+\sin x}2\right)=\frac{x+\sin x}2$$

Try now to take it from here.

Comment: But what do we do in the intervals$ [\pi,2\pi]~and~[2\pi,4\pi]$ as in the interval $ [\pi,2\pi],~ f(x)=\frac{ x+sinx}{2} $ only till $x+sinx=2$ after which it would become $ f(x)=\pi-\frac{ x+sinx}{2} $ for some x.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal I can't understand that. The function is *explicitly* defined for $\;x\in[0,\pi]\;$ . What business have $\;x\in[\pi,2\pi],\,[2\pi,4\pi]\;$ I can't say...but perhaps they mean you "extend" the definition of $\;f\;$ to those intervals...That looks like a mistake to me. Perhaps the definition interval was $\;[0,4\pi]\;$ and you have to figure out what to do in separate intervals...

Comment: Yup, you were right, I got the answer. I instead stick-ed to my initial approach, one thing that I did different this time was differentiating the function without defining a specific interval for x. Then, getting increase and decrease in the function, which had multiple solutions (trigonometric solutions) which easily gave out all the three answers _that too without the use of the mess given in the question_. Thanks a lot.

Comment: fiitjee? I recognise the font

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for $x \in [0, \pi]$ we have that

$$f(x)=\frac{x+ \sin x}{2}.$$